# My Press and hold accents have been disabled in Yosemite

Tags: terminal, macbook-pro, macos

I just got Yosemite and now my Press and hold accent capability seems to have disappeared with my old software.

I tried using `/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app` in Terminal to find Press And Hold but it comes up saying

> -bash: System/Library/Input: No such file or directory

and I am not even able to use `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`

to enable it. Please help!

Comment: As the answer shows you have two questions here please edit this one down and create another

Answer (score 1):

I just realised you need to restart the device for it to take effect...

Answer (score 0):

Your error in Terminal happened because you didn’t escape the space. It read `/System/Library/Input` as one thing, and `Methods/PressAndHold.app` as another separate thing. And if you don’t tell it to `open` the app, it’ll just complain that the app bundle is a directory.

What you needed to do was either type a backslash `\` before the space (this is done automatically if you drag a file into the Terminal window or autocomplete a name by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>):

`$ open /System/Library/Input\ Methods/PressAndHold.app`

or put quotes around the whole path:

`$ open "/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app"`

Or just navigate to the app in Finder and double-click it.

Doesn’t really answer the problem you asked about, but I hope this helps you in using Terminal.